# Numpy nanmean and dataframe (possible bug?)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm wondering if this is a bug, or possibly I don't understand how nanmean should work with a dataframe.  Seems to work if I convert the dataframe to an array, but not directly on the dataframe, nor is any exception raised.  Originally noticed here:  [Fill data gaps with average of data from adjacent days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909115/fill-data-gaps-with-average-of-data-from-adjacent-days)

```
df1 = DataFrame({ 'x': [1,3,np.nan] })
df2 = DataFrame({ 'x': [2,np.nan,5] })

    x
0   1
1   3
2 NaN

    x
0   2
1 NaN
2   5

In [1503]: np.nanmean( [df1,df2], axis=0 )
Out[1503]: 
     x
0  1.5
1  NaN
2  NaN

In [1504]: np.nanmean( [df1.values, df2.values ], axis=0 )
Out[1504]: 
array([[ 1.5],
       [ 3. ],
       [ 5. ]])
```

Comment: this looks like a bug to me but unclear if this is Pandas or numpy's fault as historically there have been a few problems where the conversion to numpy array is not made, I've encountered this in scikit learn a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390084/valueerror-array-contains-nan-or-infinity-in-assert-all-finite-during-linearsv/21410340#21410340 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095725/getting-scikit-learn-to-work-with-pandas

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669208/attributeerror-series-object-has-no-attribute-searchsorted-pandas/22669229#22669229. this could be an issue with numpy not calling `__array__` so I don't know if this is really a bug with pandas

Comment: I guess the lesson is to not generally assume numpy will translate a dataframe or series the way you think it will.  Just use .values when there is any doubt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely strange behavior. I don't have the answers, but it mostly seems that entire pandas `DataFrames` can be elements of numpy arrays, which results in strange behavior. I'm guessing this should be avoided as much as possible, and I'm not sure why `DataFrames` are valid numpy elements at all.

`np.nanmean` probably converts the arguments into an `np.array` before applying operations. So lets look at

```
a = np.array([df1, df2])
```

First note that this is not a 3-d array like you might think, it's actually a 1-d array, where each *element* is a `DataFrame`.

```
print(a.shape)
# (2,)

print(type(a[0]))
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

So `nanmean` is taking the mean of both of the `DataFrame`s, not of the values inside the dataframes. This also means that the axis argument isn't actually doing anything, and if you try using `axis=1` you'll get an error because it's a 1-d array.

```
np.nanmean(a, axis=1)
# IndexError: tuple index out of range

print(np.nanmean(a))
#      x
# 0  1.5
# 1  NaN
# 2  NaN
```

---

That's why you're getting a different answer than when you create the array with values. When you use values, it properly creates the 3-d array of numbers, rather than the weird 1-d array of dataframes.

```
b = np.array([df1.values, df2.values ])

print(b.shape)
# (2, 3, 1)

print(type(b[1]))
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

print(type(b[0,0,0]))
# <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

---

These arrays of dataframes have some especially weird behavior though. Say that we make a 3-length array where the third element is `np.nan`. You might expect to get the same answer from `nanmean` as we did with `a` before, as it should exclude the `nan` value, right?

```
print(np.nanmean(np.array([df1, df2, np.nan])))
#     x
# 0 NaN
# 1 NaN
# 2 NaN
```

Yea, so I'm not sure. Best to avoid making these.

Comment: `I'm not sure why DataFrames are valid numpy elements at all` pandas is built on numpy arrays but the key thing here is to not expect it to always behave like you think, especially wrt to dataframes: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe-interoperability-with-numpy-functions